# htaccess alias domain to main domain AND keep the filename

Tags: .htaccess, domain-aliasing

I have 2 additional domains which I want to use as aliases to my main domain. I have this setup in my htaccess but it is not 100% right. Whenever I access a page from either one of the 2 domains it always redirects to the main domain index page.

e.g. going to https://bumpstudios.com/downloads redirects to https://www.bumpstudios.co.uk/ when it needs to redirect to https://www.bumpstudios.co.uk/downloads

here is my htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.bumpstudios.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteBase /

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bumpstudios.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bumpstudios.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bumpstudios.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bumpstudios.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bumpstudios.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.bumpstudios.co.uk/{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more fiddling the issue now seems to be fixed. I removed the RewriteBase / and put the domain rewriteCond rules near the top. Seems to have done the trick. Here is the modified version

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.bumpstudios.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bumpstudios.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bumpstudios.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bumpstudios.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bumpstudios.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bumpstudios.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.bumpstudios.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# RewriteBase /

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Incidentally, this has nothing to do with `RewriteBase` - it just so happens this is superfluous in your current config so it not required. Your directives can be simplified - I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bumpstudios.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bumpstudios.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bumpstudios.uk$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bumpstudios.uk$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bumpstudios.co.uk$
> RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.bumpstudios.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This could be simplified... instead of matching all the domains/hostnames it shouldn't be, you could simply use a negated condition (`!` prefix) and match the single canonical hostname.

For example:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.bumpstudios.co.uk
 RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bumpstudios.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If it's not `www.example.co.uk` then redirect to `www.example.co.uk`. This uses a lexicographical string comparison (`=` prefix), not a regex. So the literal dots do not need to be escaped (something that was missing from your regex above).

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.bumpstudios.co.uk/{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

You were missing a `%` from `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

But as you found, the order of these directives is important.